# Resizing NSTextField within Xcode 4 to fit default font?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode4

In XCode 4, if I change the font of an NSTextField its frame does not update to accommodate the change.  Further, under "Frame layout" its height is grayed-out and unalterable.  Is there a quick way to adjust the frame of the NSTextField to fit its font choice without having to resort to a programmatic adjustment?  Hopefully I have overlooked a simple control in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a somewhat awkward solution:  by setting the "Line break" to "Word wrap" I was allowed to adjust the the height of the NSTextView in the Size inspector.  I simply restored my "Line break" configuration when done.