# Change the line height (leading) in NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

Does anyone know how to change the line height (leading) on a textfield, preferably in Interface Builder?

I have been searching for this for about an hour but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is here:

[Resizing NSTextField within Xcode 4 to fit default font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659888/resizing-nstextfield-within-xcode-4-to-fit-default-font)

(it is the OP that answers his own question :) ).

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do this in IB by choose the NSTextField and then opening the font panel. I believe it has a setting for leading.

Failing that, you can do it in code by applying an [NSParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000375) using the lineSpacing property.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I didn't find the setting in the font panel, I will check if it works later today! If it works I will accept your answer! Thanks!